# c++ understanding a circular doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem figuring out how to set my ptr's for prev and next when I add a node with at least one existing node. Adding the first node is easy, just setting the ptrs to the front. I need help viewing this mentally, also this program is a queue so each node gets added to the back of the list.

```
if (Empty())
    {
        front = new qnode;
        front->next=front;
        front->prev=front;
        front->data = item;
    }
    else if (front->prev=front)
    {
        front->prev = new qnode;
        front->prev->next= front;
        front->next=front->prev;
        front->prev->data = item;
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

What i have now still not getting it

```
else
    {
        front->prev= new qnode;
        front->prev->data= item;
        front->prev->next=front;
        front->prev=front->prev->prev;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this image helps a bit [image]

I have created pictures for 1 item 2 items and 3 items

the pointers just point to the actual object meaning the black rectangle is the whole object if front being blue and prev being brown(those are just there as references)

I really hope this helps linked list can get really tricky and drawing always helps me.

so to add the item at the front of the list you have some code like this:

```
 //ok first I'll define some variables for you
 //last === the last node in the list
 //head === the first node in the list
 //node === the new node you are adding;
 qnode node = new qnode;
 node.data = data; //whatever data you are holding
 node->next = last; //last element in the list since it is circular;
 node->prev = head; //you want the new node to point the the first node since it's getting added before that;
 head->next = node; //you want the head of the node to point to the new node not the last item
 last->prev = node; //last node now should point to the new node you just added not the head;
```

[image]

Comment: @Randblack yeah the only one that may be confusing is the last one where the 'New Node's' brown POINTS to the first Node and the First Node's Blue points to the 'New Node'.

Comment: this is adding to the front of the list, I'm trying to add to the back, i''ll try drawing that and figuring it out.

Comment: @Randblack yeah that will be good practice, the diagram should be a good reference.

Comment: Great contribution! more people should see this diagram.

Comment: I don't think I'm getting it, this is what i have now                               else
 {
  front->prev= new qnode;
  front->prev->time= wha;
  front->prev->next=front;
  front->prev=front->prev->prev;

 }

Comment: @Randblack I added some pseudo code to help with adding an element to the front.

Comment: ok gonna write it out and try it, i'm trying to understand just adding one onto an existing node.

Comment: Your patience on paint is admirable. :D
Nice work! :)

Comment: @Randblack I have added a second picture to help illustrate what is going on.

Comment: this is what i have seems to work thank you so much!                                          else
 {
  qnode* p= new qnode;
  p->data=item;

  p->next=front->prev;
  p->prev=front;
  front->next=p;
  front->prev=p;

 }

Comment: @Randblack this will really only work for doubly linked list with two items not more. you really need to keep a ref of last and first because what will happen when you add a fourth is the truly last element will be hanging and the list will be pointing to the first 3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need an `else if`, as I think the case with one element is not different from that with multiple elements. In any case you have a syntax error there - you wanted to write `==` instead of `=`.

More to the point, what you want to do is:

- Create a new qnode
- Set the data of the new node to the item
- Set the next of the new node to the front
- Set the prev of the new node to front->prev
- Set the prev of the front to the new node.

You may check for yourself on a piece of paper how this works.

Comment: what is new node set to when it is created? front?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. New node is set to a new qnode, which you fill with the new data item and then you insert it into the list by making `front->prev` (aka `back`) and `front` point to it. However, before you do that you need to make the newly created node point to the original values of `front` and `back`, because you will otherwise lose the pointers.

Comment: what i meant was when creating a new qnode do  you set to front this way front= new qnode?

Comment: No, front stays the way it is, if you want to insert the node at the back. You will do something like `qnode* newNode = new qnode(); newNode->data = item; newNode->next = front; front->prev = newNode;`.
Why don't you try putting what I said earlier into code - it translates pretty literally - and see if you can follow the logic.

Answer (score 0):

In a circular doubly linked list, you have 2 pointers, one to the head and one to the tail (last element in the list). If a element has a next, the next element's prev should be the element pointing at it through it's next element. 
Your head pointer should never move unless the head element is removed. Your tail will move along always ensuring that the element it points to has head as it's next element. 
Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you always add at the end, the case of a queue with a single element is identical with the case of a list with multiple elements. Take a paper and a pen, make some sketches and it will come very easy to you.

Comment: Been trying that, and the result i got is what i put in the else if case.